# i am getting errors when i try to use gspread (python)

Tags: python, api, authentication, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to access a Google Sheets spreadsheet from a Python program using the gspread library. However, when I try to open the spreadsheet using the open_by_key() function, I am getting the following error:

vbnet

google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.'})

I understand that this error is related to the authentication token being used to access the spreadsheet, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Can anyone provide guidance on how to:

```
Obtain a new authentication token that meets the requirements (i.e. a short-lived token within a reasonable timeframe)
Update the existing token with the correct values for the "iat" and "exp" fields in the JWT claim
Verify if the token being used is valid and meets the requirements
Diagnose and resolve any other authentication-related issues that may be causing the error
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Fixed error and working code